# Django | ListView con Form para filtrar devuelve error "name 'request' is not defined"

Tags: django, django-models

Tratando de filtra con form, no consigo que filtre por la palabra que se introduce. Muestra el siguiente error:

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo** views.py

```
class StationList(ListView):
    model = Station
    template_name = 'station/station_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            name = self.kwargs['kword']
        except:
            name = ''
        if (name != ''):
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(name__icontains = name)
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'station/station_list.html', {'stations': object_list})
```

**Archivo** station_list.html

```
    <form method="GET">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" id="kword" name="kword" placeholder="ingrese nombre">
      <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>

    {% for station in stations %}
     <a href="{% url 'detalle_estacion' station.id %}">{{ station.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**Archivo** urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',
        views.StationList.as_view(),
        name='station_list',
    ),
]
```

Gracias.

Comment: Podrias agregar tu ```urls.py```

Comment: Claro! Ahí está! Gracias lankos!

Comment: Hola, por lo que veo en este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416502/django-search-form-in-class-based-listview solo es regresar to object list no hacer un render

Comment: @lankos tiene razón, el método `get_queryset` debe retornar un QuerySet, es decir devuelve la lista de elementos para esta vista, no debes hacer eso en dicho método... haces aberraciones jajaj XDD

Comment: Muy amables. ¿Cómo puedo agradecer vuestro interés y voluntad en ayudar? Julio Cesar siempre ahí! xD Siento cometer tantos errores de novato como novato que soy xD

Comment: @julian No importa, de los errores se aprende jaja xD

Comment: ¿Recuerdas Julio Cesar cuando no sabías? Asi me siento yo. xD